# Rails most occurrence of day of week from date field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In rails 5 project with postgres I have to get most occurrence of day of week from date time field
Like Log table

```
ID date
1  01-12-2017  //Day is Friday here
2  01-12-2017  //Day is Friday here
3  02-12-2017  //Day is Saturday here
4  02-11-2017  //Day is Thursday here
5  02-10-2017  //Day is Monday here
```

So the most occurred day of week is **FRIDAY with count 2 against ID 1 & 2**

I can group by with week of day to get such results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the gem [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate)

And you can do a query like:

```
records = YOURMODEL.group_by_day_of_week(:date).count
day = Hash[records.sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse].first[0]
```

this day will have day like 1,2 etc to show monday, tuesday.

Comment: group_by_day of groupdate works on base of day of month like 1,15,25,31 etc. not by day of week like monday, tuesday etc.

Comment: but group_by_day_of_week can kind of work with sorting etc.

Comment: sorry, yes YOURMODEL.group_by_day_of_week(:date).count is the best answer for you. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, it gives hash & than sort it by value of has will work